# Adding columns in panda with and without filter

Tags: pandas, filtering

I'm new to pandas. I'm trying to add columns to my `df`. There are multiple columns in the `csv`. The names of the columns include, "Name", "Date", ..., "Problem", "Problem.1", "Problem.2" etc.  The user is going to be downloading the files at different times and the number of problems will change so I can't just list the problems.

I only want the columns: Name, Date, and all columns whose *name* contains the word "Problem".
I know this isn't correct but the idea is...

```
df=df['Name', 'Date', df.filter (regex = 'Problem')]
```

Any help is appreciated.Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```py
df [ ['Name', 'Date'] + [col for col in df.columns if 'Problem' in col] ]
```